# Panel locations moved

Tags: panel

Opened my project today and the panels were in different places. Very uncomfortable to use. How do I move them back to the default location? [image]

Comment: Just rearrange the screen as you wish by sliding the limits of the panels, any right click on them (the panels borders) will open a contextual menu with choice to either split or merge screens, and at least you can obviously change any panel to another type (3Dview, Outliner...).

Answer (score 1):

This will return all settings, including UI, to those you had when you downloaded Blender.... this will also reset any changes you have made to the Blender start-up file, too.

[image]

and this will allow you to load files containing alternate UIs without loading the UI changes... (just in case that is what happened...)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Close the project.

Open Blender.

Use File Open (or  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> ) select the project you want to open and make sure that the **Load UI** is Unchecked

[image]

Your project will load using your default scene layout.